# Android one values folder for multiple languages

Tags: android

Is there a way to tag a strings resource folder with more than one language(values-en-es)?

My problem is that for Hebrew on some devices the language code "iw" and on others it is "he".
My current solution is to make two folders with the same content and only change their name
respectively.

I wonder if there is a more accurate way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a **File Link in eclipse**, as described [here](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/tasks/tasks-45.htm).
So you have your `values-iw/strings.xml` with the real values and you make a *File Link* to that file in your `values-he` folder. This has the benefit that you do not have to edit 2 files, the linked 'file' gets updated automatically.

Comment: my solution was to create an ANT script that duplicates and and change the name of the folders. before i publish the application i just run it.
I didn't know about file link, I'll check it out.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Resource folder names can have multiple qualifiers but only one qualifier per type:

For example

```
values-en-rGB //Language + Region
```

is valid but

```
values-en-fr//Language + Language
```

is not valid, since it has multiple values for a single qualifier. So

```
values-iw-he
```

is not possible.

Source: Android Developers, Q[ualifier Name Rules.](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#QualifierRules)

However this doesn't mean you have to duplicate the files. Instead, you can create an ***Alias Resource***.

Android Developers explains Alias Resouces like this:

> Creating Alias Resources: When you have a resource that you'd like to use for more than one device configuration (but do not want to provide as a default resource), you do not need to put the same resource in more than one alternative resource directory. Instead, you can (in some cases) create an alternative resource that acts as an alias for a resource saved in your default resource directory.

For example, a String resource in one folder

```
<string name="app_name">My Awesome App</string>
```

can be referenced in another String resource in another folder as:

```
<string name="application_name">@string/app_name</string>
```

[More about alias-resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AliasResources) on Android Developers.

Comment: As I understand using alias will still require me to create two folders and reference one string resource to another.
Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: You're correct. The primary benefit is you only have to do revisions/updates to one of the strings. There is also the possibility of having the strings in a string-array where one reference can refer to the whoe array of Strings. Depends on your apps requirements whether you can accept accessing array positions to retrieve individual strings. Net, if there is an xml 'object type' in the Android resources system (string, string-array etc) you can create one reference to it. But you can't create one reference to say 20 strings without encapsulating those strings in an xml object you can point to